# how do i correct this error: ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (30196)

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mlp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
olympic = pd.read_csv('Olympic_Games.csv')

olympic['BMI']=(olympic['Weight']/[olympic['Height']/100]^2)
```

I got this error:

```
ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match length of index (30196)
```

I want to create a new column 'BMI'

Comment: `^` is xor, `**` is power operator. Also you should use `()` instead of `[]`.

Comment: In Python, `^` performs a bitwise exclusive-or (XOR). To raise to a power, use `**`.  Also, `[`...`]` creates a list; you have to use only parentheses (round brackets, `(`...`)`) for grouping in expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using wrong parentheses and math operation for squaring (if you mean squaring by ^2). This should work:
`olympic['BMI']=olympic['Weight']/(olympic['Height']/100)**2`